# How to know the group name of a spark user from a spark application

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hdfs

I want to know the group name to which a particular spark user belongs from a spark application program. Currently, I can retrieve the name of a spark user using `spark.sparkContext.sparkUser`

Is there any API/method which will give me group name to which this spark user belongs.
I know there is a linux command `id <user-name>` but my requirement is to get the group name in a programmatic manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we can run shell commands in spark app.

**`Try this way once:`**

```
import sys.process._

val user_name=spark.sparkContext.sparkUser

s"id ${user_name}".! //displays group names
```

Comment: it worked. Actually I was looking for API in hadoop. Anyway thanks!